# html template vs pushing code through js

Tags: javascript, html, performance, underscore.js

Say I want to render some html dynamically. Which is better?(apart from it gives good structure to code)

```
<script type="text/template" id="some">
//some html code here
</script>
_.template($("#someid").html());
```

or

```
$("#someid").html("inserting html here");
```

Comment: I'm a great fan of templating. It gives me the opportunity to actually edit my html where I expect my HTML to be.

Comment: But browser holds template in html content. If I can push it through js, it can be just a string/array of strings. I was thinking which is costly!

Comment: Your examples aren't equivalent. The first is a template that allows substituting new values are runtime, the second is simply an opaque string. I doubt the performance difference is worth worrying about, especially if you're sensible and cache the functions that `_.template` returns so that you're only building them once.

Comment: @CaptainCarl does make a good point. It would also avoid you having to  repeatedly typing in the .html("content") as it would be in one centralized location. Regardless of the performance, use templating as it is popular for a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the approaches that you've mentioned, the HTML markup is generated as HTML string and then added to the target DOM element. So, the way I see it there is no performance benefit of using one over the other.

- Having said that, using templates (underscore) in your case, the code
  just becomes more manageable than having to generate long HTML
  strings by concatenating various values together.
- Also, compiled templates with conditional statements can be stored in a variable and reused by making a single call to the template (and passing an object to it). Whereas, if you need to populate HTML string then in that case you'll end up writing a string concatenation statement inside a `for` loop or its functional programming equivalent `$.each` or `_.each` to make it reusable.

Here are 2 fiddles that essentially do the same thing using the 2 said approaches:

[**Using Templates**](http://jsfiddle.net/aPv9H/)

[**Using string concatenation**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/LV9Mm/)

Compare the code and decide for yourself what best suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an invisible `div` rather than html code in `script` tag so google could index it.

Also I would use `.clone()` method to clone DOM structure instead of retrieving plain text html (`.html()`) and creating new element based on this. But it would be a bit more tricky to change values in the template - still it might be quicker; haven't tested.